# Strange printing issue with an Inkjet HP 2600

Tags: printer

This Inkjet HP 2600 printer started acting up this morning.

I tried resetting / (built-in) cleaning (menu - service), still same issue.

What do I need to replace / fix? Here are some sample pages for reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this OEM or after market?

Answer (score 0):

Going by the Windows test page, you seem to have fuser problem: toner is not fused correctly onto the paper, sticks to the fuser roller, and after one revolution of the roller, those bits are put onto the paper.

The first thing to check is the paper. Has there been any change in your paper type? If there was, try the old paper again. What kind of paper is it? If it is heavier than normal bond paper, try telling the printer it's heavy paper (from driver settings) and see if that fixes it.

If the paper is not the issue, then I suspect the fuser is faulty or has come to the end of its life. Fusers are typically rated at 50,000 to 100,000 pages. How many pages has the printer done?

If the fuser is at end of life, you should consider ordering a complete maintenance kit, so you can replace paper feed rollers, etc at the same time. Search "laserjet 2600 maintenance kit" to find them.